# How to implement GetHashcode for a difference-tolerant DateTime comparer?

Tags: c#, gethashcode, iequalitycomparer

I've implemented an `IEqualityComparer<DateTime>` which can compare two dates based on a tolerance value in milliseconds. If the difference between the two is less than the tolerance, they should be treated as equal.

The `Equals` side is almost trivial to implement, however I have really no idea how I could implement the `GetHashcode` to cooperate with the equality comparison.

The problem ccan be generalized for numbers as well: given two `double` and a delta value, a similar equality comparer could be implemented and the similar `GetHashcode` difficulties would arise.

Any idea would be appreciated.

EDIT

I know such an equality comparer is kind of tricky because such an equality operator would not be a transitive relation for example. Still, I'd love to hear some possible ideas or alternatives.

Comment: `return 0;` gets the job done.  Just don't create a large Dictionary or HashSet with that class as a key, performance might be a bit disappointing.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. That's my current implementation, and it works indeed. I was just looking for a more proper way,.